# How can a RabbitMQ Client tell when it loses connection to the server?

Tags: rabbitmq

If I'm connected to RabbitMQ and listening for events using an EventingBasicConsumer, how can I tell if I've been disconnected from the server?

I know there is a Shutdown event, but it doesn't fire if I unplug my network cable to simulate a failure.

I've also tried the ModelShutdown event, and CallbackException on the model but none seem to work.

EDIT-----
The one I marked as the answer is correct, but it was only part of the solution for me. There is also HeartBeat functionality built into RabbitMQ. The server specifies it in the configuration file. It defaults to 10 minutes but of course you can change that.

The client can also request a different interval for the heartbeat by setting the RequestedHeartbeat value on the ConnectionFactory instance.

Comment: You can add a heartbeat to the connection which will detect service interuption

Comment: Can you post your whole code? I am facing same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need 3 things. 1 the ConnectionFactory needs to set a RequestedHeartBeat. 2 after you create a connection define the ConnectionShutdown event as described in the marked answer. 3 ensure you have it setup correctly in the rabbitmq config file. (sorry I don't have that part around currently.) I'll see if I can extract the code without any implementation specific stuff.

Comment: I posted an example as an answer below that I hope helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using the C# library? (but even so I think the others have a similar event).

You can do the following:

```cs
public class MyRabbitConsumer
{
  private IConnection connection;

  public void Connect()
  {
    connection = CreateAndOpenConnection();
    connection.ConnectionShutdown += connection_ConnectionShutdown;
  }

  public IConnection CreateAndOpenConnection() { ... }

  private void connection_ConnectionShutdown(IConnection connection, ShutdownEventArgs reason)
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of it, but the marked answer is what lead me to this.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "MY_HOST_NAME",
    UserName = "USERNAME",
    Password = "PASSWORD",
    RequestedHeartbeat = 30
};

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionShutdown += (o, e) =>
    {                       
        //handle disconnect                            
    };

    using (var model = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        model.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
        var queueName = model.QueueDeclare();

        model.QueueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "#"); 

        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(model);
        model.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

        while (!stop)
        {
            BasicDeliverEventArgs args;                       
            consumer.Queue.Dequeue(5000, out args);

            if (stop) return;

            if (args == null) continue;
            if (args.Body.Length == 0) continue;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Do work here on different thread then this one
            }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
        }
    }
}
```

A few things to note about this.

I'm using # for the topic. This grabs everything. Usually you want to limit by a topic.

I'm setting a variable called "stop" to determine when the process should end. You'll notice the loop runs forever until that variable is true.

The Dequeue waits 5 seconds then leaves without getting data if there is no new message. This is to ensure we listen for that stop variable and actually quit at some point. Change the value to your liking.

When a message comes in I spawn the handling code on a new thread. The current thread is being reserved for just listening to the rabbitmq messages and if a handler takes too long to process I don't want it slowing down the other messages. You may or may not need this depending on your implementation. Be careful however writing the code to handle the messages. If it takes a minute to run and your getting messages at sub-second times you will run out of memory or at least into severe performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a shutdown listener **(conn.addShutdownListener)**. When there is anything wrong with the connection you will be able to listen the reason. Look how to do it.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
factory.setUsername("user");
factory.setPassword("yourpass");
factory.setPort("5671");
Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
conn.addShutdownListener(new ShutdownListener() {
    public void shutdownCompleted(ShutdownSignalException cause) {
        System.out.println("Connection closed by a reason" + cause.toString())
    }
});
```

More info here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html